# Deserialize JSON - nested lists and key needed as value

Tags: java, json, key-value, json-deserialization

I need to deserialize this in Java 1.7 with Jackson, using currency as value:

```
"prices": {
    "USD": [
        [1, "1.99000"],
        [100, "1.89000"],
        [1000, "1.40500"]
    ],
    "EUR": [
        [1, "1.53000"],
        [100, "1.45000"],
        [1000, "1.08350"]
    ]
}
```

(source is this REST API https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/rest-api#notes-partoffer.prices)

My goal is to get objects for each Price with attributes currency, price break and price.

I can't figure out how to perform that. I tried the following:

1. deserialize the whole "prices" as String for further processing (didn't work, got Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token - obviously, since this is JSON_OBJECT)
2. deserialize like

   ```
   LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>>
   ```

(inspired by this [Deserializing Jackson by using a key as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033272/deserializing-jackson-by-using-a-key-as-value), but also didn't work)

3. use a wrapper like this:

   ```
   public class PartOfferPriceWrapper {

   private LinkedHashMap<String, List<Entry<Integer, String>>> prices;

   }
   ```

and then process like:

```
List<PartOfferPrice> partOfferPriceList = new ArrayList<PartOfferPrice>();

  for (Entry<String, List<Entry<Integer, String>>> currencyEntry : 
    partOfferPrices.entrySet()) {

      for (Entry<Integer, String> priceEntry : currencyEntry.getValue()) {
        PartOfferPrice partOfferPrice = new PartOfferPrice();

        partOfferPrice.setOffer_id(partOfferId);
        partOfferPrice.setCurrency(currencyEntry.getKey());
        partOfferPrice.setPriceBreak(priceEntry.getKey());              

        partOfferPrice.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceEntry.getValue()));

        partOfferPriceList.add(partOfferPrice);
        }
```

This seems fine, but the result is empty (it's a part of bigger response, reading with Response.readEntity was successful). I can't find any other way how to process this (some custom deserializer?).

**EDIT**

I tried to use custom deserializer following tima's advice:

```
    public class PartOfferPricesWrapperDeserializer extends 
    JsonDeserializer<PartOfferPricesWrapper> {

    public PartOfferPricesWrapperDeserializer() { super(); }

    @Override
    public PartOfferPricesWrapper deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
        DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, 
        JsonProcessingException {

        PartOfferPricesWrapper partOfferPricesWrapper = new 
        PartOfferPricesWrapper();
        List<PartOfferPrice> priceList = new ArrayList<PartOfferPrice>();

        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodes = 
        node.get("prices").fields();

        while (nodes.hasNext()) {               
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = nodes.next();               
            for (JsonNode tempNode : entry.getValue()) {

                PartOfferPrice price = new PartOfferPrice();
                price.setCurrency(entry.getKey());

                for (int i = 0; i < tempNode.size(); i++) {

                    if (tempNode.get(i).isInt()) {
                        price.setPriceBreak(tempNode.get(i).intValue());                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        price.setPrice(tempNode.get(i).asDouble());                         
                    }                                           
                }

            priceList.add(price);
            }
        }
        partOfferPricesWrapper.setPrices(priceList);
        return partOfferPricesWrapper;
    }
}
```

adding this to the handler method:

```
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(PartOfferPricesWrapper.class, new 
    PartOfferPricesWrapperDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);          

    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, 
    false);
    partsMatchResponse = objectMapper.readValue(target.getUri().toURL(), 
    PartsMatchResponse.class);
```

Which would probably work if the response contains only "prices" node, but now I'm getting NullPointerException on node.get("prices").fields(); It is probably trying to parse the whole response, but I need to use the custom deserializer only for the "prices" part. Is it somehow possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a custom deserializer would work.

```
class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Prices> {

    public CustomDeserializer() { super(); }

    @Override
    public Prices deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodes = node.get("prices").fields();

        while (nodes.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = nodes.next();

            System.out.println(entry.getKey());

            for (JsonNode tempNode : entry.getValue()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempNode.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(tempNode.get(i).getClass() + "\t" + tempNode.get(i));
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Output

```
USD
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode   1
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode  "1.99000"
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode   100
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode  "1.89000"
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode   1000
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode  "1.40500"

EUR
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode   1
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode  "1.53000"
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode   100
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode  "1.45000"
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode   1000
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode  "1.08350"
```

You can create the object and structure that you want in the deserializer (`Prices` is an empty class I used).

**EDIT**

You can use the same custom deserializer just for the field with a small change.

The first two lines become like shown below, because you do not need to look for the `prices` node because when it deserializes the field it will only pass the JSON for that field. The rest of the lines are the same.

```
JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodes = node.fields();
```

Then in your wrapper class:

```
class PricesWrapper {

    // ...

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private Prices prices;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try it. But since Price is only a small part of the response (is related to PriceOffer, which is related to Part, but all is one chunk of data), it seems that i wil have to custom deserialize the whole response?

Comment: @budul you're welcome. I've edited the question for a field deserialization.

Comment: Tima, it works! I really appreciate your help since I spent almost two days trying to solve it and today I should present some results... Only one thing annoys me - that I was unable to solve it on my own :-) (and even had to register to SO...). Many thanks.