# Map JSON key-value to class in java

Tags: java, json, mapping, objectmapper

I need to map string JSON by key-value into the [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12518297/1193179) class, but I'm not sure there is an easier way to convert this.

My class:

```
class Colors {
    
    private String name;

    private String color;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public String getColor() { return color; }

}
```

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "white": "FFFFFF",
    "red": "FF0000",
    "black": "000000"
}
```

Is there any way (instead of using foreach loop) to have the above JSON in `List<Colors>`?

*P.s: I tried some same issue with `objectMapper.readValue`, but didn't succeed.*

Comment: Have you tried [Jackson JSON processor](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#1-minute-tutorial-pojos-to-json-and-back)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter` annotation which will allow you to handle each `key-value` pair:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./src/main/resources/test.json");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Colors colors = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Colors.class);
        System.out.println(colors.getColors());
    }
}

class Colors {
    private final List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAny(String key, String value) {
        colors.add(new Color(key, value));
    }

    public List<Color> getColors() {
        return colors;
    }
}

class Color {

    private String name;
    private String color;

    public Color(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Color{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[Color{name='white', color='FFFFFF'}, Color{name='red', color='FF0000'}, Color{name='black', color='000000'}]
```

See also:

- [Deserializing Jackson by using a key as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033272/deserializing-jackson-by-using-a-key-as-value/19046008#19046008)

Comment: Yesss... Thanks a lot!!!! Your method worked well for me and my issue has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

change your json object to:

```
{
"listcolors": [
    {
        "name": "white",
        "color": "FFFFFF"
    },
    {
        "name": "red",
        "color": "FF0000"
    },
    {
        "name": "black",
        "color": "000000"
    }
]}
```

your color class should implement serializable

```
 class Colors implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private String color;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public String getColor() { return color; }

}
```

Now create a list of colors class to receive the deserialization of your object

```
class ListColors implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<Color> ListColors = new ArrayList<Color>();
}
```

then:

```
ListColors objColors = new Gson().fromJson(<
        put your json object string here>, Colors.class);
```

See more about the GSON library [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but for some reason, I get this JSON from another API and I can't change the format. :(